# Convert plain text to a pdf template

Tags: workflows, templates, markup, pdf

I have some articles (more than 200 pages) in plain text. It needs to be converted to an given PDF markup. I got some Photoshop files for the headers for every page and a list of requirements for the different elements.

Which program would you use? And what would be your workflow?

Comment: What about MS word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How much customization are you looking for?

Ballpark guess would be [LaTeX](http://www.latex-project.org/), unless you want to do actual transformations there is no need to pull out a general purpose language.

Comment: @user1386906 There is also tex.stackexchange.com to help you with it ! :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you would need a workflow.

There is already a very reliable tool to assist you with this task. Just look at this amazing [**ABCpdf**](http://www.websupergoo.com/abcpdf-1.htm) tool. We have used it in three projects so far, and have no complains.